# How to run code when user stops pressing a button?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit

I have an eye button next to my password textfield which is suppose to set to false the secure text entry property of the textfield for the time the user presses, it should end when the user removes his finger.

I successfully managed to set the property to false when the user presses using a target with the touchUpInside event, but I don't know how to detect that this event has stopped. And this what I'm looking for.

Before that I have used the long press gesture recognizer, but the problem is that the code was taking too much time to kick in. Which is normal because it's a long presse but it is not the behavior I want.

My code was :

```
let gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(eyePressed(sender:)))
passwordEyeButton.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

@objc func eyePressed(sender : UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
    switch sender.state {
    case .began :
        passwordEyeButton.setImage(eyeImage, for: .normal)
        passwordTextField.isSecureTextEntry = false
    case .ended :
        passwordEyeButton.setImage(crossedEyeImage, for: .normal)
        passwordTextField.isSecureTextEntry = true
    default :
        print("default state")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manage 3 events: `.touchDown`, `.touchUpInside` and `.touchUpOutside`.

Your intention is to show the password when the button is pressed, and hide it when the finger is released, and therefore if you only implement `.touchUpInside` to detect that user stopped pressing a button it will **NOT** work if it releases the finger outside the button.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showPassword), for: .touchDown)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(hidePassword), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(hidePassword), for: .touchUpOutside)   
}

@objc func showPassword(_ sender: Any) {
    print("show password")
}

@objc func hidePassword(_ sender: Any) {
    print("hide password")
}
```

Comment: Why touch up Outside ?

Answer (score 1):

Add a touch down event and a touch up inside event for your button:

You can use the storyboard to add them so no need to add the targets manually.

```
//Touch down
@IBAction func touched(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("show password")
}

//Touch up inside 
 @IBAction func touchUp(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("hide password")
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add two targets to `UIButton` for two events:

- `touchDown` for handle when button is pressed
- `touchUpInside` for handle when user move his finger from the button

---

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    passwordEyeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressBegan(_:)), for: .touchDown)
    passwordEyeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressEnded(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc func pressBegan(_ sender: UIButton) {
    passwordEyeButton.setImage(eyeImage, for: .normal)
    passwordTextField.isSecureTextEntry = false
}

@objc func pressEnded(_ sender: UIButton) {
    passwordEyeButton.setImage(crossedEyeImage, for: .normal)
    passwordTextField.isSecureTextEntry = true
}
```